# Evolutionarily stable strategy and Harm thy neighbor

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, evolutionary-game-theory

I'm studying ESS, and I have found the harm my neighbor example on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionarily_stable_strategy

in Examples of differences between Nash equilibria and ESSes

Now I don't understand why only B,B is ESS. Wikipedia says:

"This dynamic is captured by Maynard Smith's second condition, since E(A, A) = E(B, A), but it is not the case that E(A,B) > E(B,B)"

but we can do the same reasoning with B,B:

E(B, B) = E(B, A), but it is not the case that E(B,A) > E(A,A)

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to swap all the variables. The analogue of $E(A,A)=E(B,A)$ is not $E(B,B)=E(B,A)$ but $E(B,B)=E(A,B)$, and that’s not true; in fact $E(B,B)\gt E(A,B)$, so the first condition for an evolutionarily stable strategy is fulfilled.

Comment: E(B,B) = E(A,B) is true on columns 2=2

Comment: @MementoMori: Please explain precisely what you mean by that. As I said, $E(B,B)\gt E(A,B)$.

Comment: It is E(B,B) > E(A,B) for player 1 (row player) but for second player  is equal.

Comment: @MementoMori: I'm sorry, I can't follow you. You're going to have to be more precise. $E(B,B)$ and $E(A,B)$ are well-defined game results; they don't exist "for" one player or the other.

Comment: Probably I'm not understanding the notation, when there is the (2,2) for example, this represents the payoff for the first player and the payoff for the second player, isn't it? When I write E(B,B) what is it? One of the payoff of a player or the average of payoff?

Comment: @MementoMori: The notation is defined further up in the Wikipedia article: "Let $E(S,T)$ represent the payoff for playing strategy $S$ against strategy $T$." So this is the payoff that a player with strategy $S$ gets when playing against a player with strategy $T$. Since the game is symmetric, there's no need to specify which player is player $1$ or player $2$; the payoff is determined only by the strategies.